# What languages are these?

Tags: written-language, writing-systems, language-identification

Sorry if this question is rather dumb and ignorant for this community, but nevertheless -

In the following image I am having hard time recognizing most of the names of the languages, particularly the 3rd and 4th panel.

[image]

Could someone provide a list of the languages mentioned in the image, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leftmost: Belarusian.

1st panel: Bulgarian, Kyrgyz, Kazakh, Macedonian, Mongolian, Russian, Serbian, Ukrainian, Georgian, Armenian.

2nd panel: Hebrew, Uyghur, Urdu, Arabic, Pashto, Farsi, Tigrinya, Amharic, Nepali, Marathi.

3rd panel: Hindi, Bengali, Punjabi, Gujarati, Oriya, Tamil, Telugu, Kannada, Malayalam, Sinhalese.

4th panel: Thai, Lao, Burmese, Khmer, Korean, Japanese, Chinese (simplified characters), Chinese (traditional characters).